# Why can't voltage in a capacitor change instantaneously?

Tags: capacitance, voltage

The voltage-current equation in a capacitor is given as

$$I(t) = C\frac{dV}{dt}$$

Isn't $\frac{dV}{dt}$ by definition the instantaneous change in voltage with respect to time?

How does one show from this equation that voltage cannot change instantaneously?

Answer (score 3):

If the voltage changes instantly from one value to another (i.e. discontinuously), the derivative is not finite. This implies that an infinite current would be required to instantly change the voltage.

Since an infinite current is not physically realizable, that means that the voltage cannot change instantaneously.

Comment: Isn't $dV$ the change in velocity from a time $t_o$ to $t_o + dt$?
So if $dt$ is infinitesimal, doesn't that make $dV$ an instantaneous change?

Comment: $dV$ is also infinitesimal, though (and also voltage, not velocity). It occurs over zero time, but it's zero change, so you'd hardly call that "instantaneous change." To get a real change, you multiply the derivative by the amount of time elapsed. (Or more generally, integrate it)

Comment: So I shouldn't interpret the derivative of the voltage in the same way as velocity, the derivative of displacement?

Comment: I don't follow. Displacement is the same way: just because the derivative is non-zero, you don't think this means your displacement can change suddenly, right?

Comment: @ArnoldDoveman The conventional $d/dt$ notation does not mean that things change in jumps.